# HTML Combo Box selected Item's value

Tags: javascript, html, combobox

Im trying to make this HTML combo box equal to a value.

`<select name="file_type">
     <option value=".jpg">.JPG</option>
     <option value=".png">.PNG</option>
     <option value=".gif">.GIF</option>
</select>`

So when i select jpg on my web page, does that mean that file_type = .jpg? I'd think so.

So then im trying to call that value from javascript, like so:

`var fileType = document.getElementByID("file_type").value;`

is that how it is done? How else can I get the value of the selected item in the combo box?

Regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First your control has no `ID` attribute set only name so you need to add the id to the html

```
<select id="file_type" name="file_type" >
```

Then the way you get the selected of a combo is like:

```
var selectCtrl = document.getElementById("file_type");
var selectedItem = selectCtrl.options[selectCtrl.selectedIndex];
```

This `selectedItem` has to properties `value` and text:

```
selectedItem.value //<--  ".jpg"
```

and

```
selectedItem.text //<-- ".JPG"
```

**[Online Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2s5ga25b/)**

Comment: Thanks heaps. I'll try that now.

Comment: Watch out that `selectedIndex` may equals -1 in some cases.

Comment: When I add those variables in the JavaScript it does not work. Using the console in Chrome it says it cant find the javascript function or something:

"unexpected ReferenceError: [functionname] is not defined. onClick. "

I call the funciton with a button. 

This works if i remove comment out those variables. What is happening?

Comment: Chrome. It just says its got something to do with the onclick not recognizing the function, but if i remove the variable its fine.. 

But in aptana it says its this:


<img src="example.com/images/120 + 'selectedItem.value'"/>

Comment: this  `<img src="example.com/images/120 + 'selectedItem.value'"/> ` is totally different of what you asked and yes it will not work but the sample above is correct and answers your questions.

Comment: I said I wanted to get the value. If i were to put the url link into a variable and call it from JavaScript that works. So why cant  I use the value of the combo box?

Effectively, all that src url will equal is "example.com/images/120.jpg" or png or gif

Comment: ok, how am i able to plug it into javascript document.write methods as a variable?